# robocopy switch(/xf) breaks script

Tags: robocopy

I have a script built to copy files using robocopy.  Code is below.  When I add the switch /xf thumbs.db the log file states the destination and source were not included and the files are not copied.

Am I missing something?

```
 SET switch1=/r:30 /w:1 /np /s /mt /log:"F:\Backup.log"

 SET source="\\server\folder"
 SET destination="F:\folder"

 FOR  /d %%i IN ("%source%\*") DO ROBOCOPY %switch1% "%%i" "%destination%\%%~nxi"
 FOR /d %%p IN ("%source%\*.*") DO RMDIR "%%p" /s /q
 CD /d %destination%
 FOR /d %%i IN (*.*) DO RD "%%i" > NUL 2>&1
```

Comment: I figured this one out myself.  It was simply wrong position in syntax.  I moved the %switch1% to the end of the line and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this one out myself.  It was simply wrong position in syntax.  I moved the %switch1% to the end of the line and it works.

```
FOR  /d %%i IN ("%source%\*") DO ROBOCOPY "%%i" "%destination%\%%~nxi" %switch1%
```